# Как в обычном SQL запросе, используя только SELECT, объявлять переменную для использования ее в условиях выборки?

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, переменные, скрипт

Пример запроса и использование переменой ниже. Чтобы каждый раз менять нужное число не во всех блоках, а только в начале скрипта в виде переменой, для дальнейшего запуска через местный SQL менеджер (RunScript см. ниже).

```
/*переменая a = 1234*/

SELECT BLOCK1.cl1, BLOCK2.cl2 
FROM 
(SELECT a, b FROM table1
WHERE TIN = /*переменая*/) BLOCK1
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT a, b FROM table2
WHERE TIN = /*переменая*/) BLOCK2
 ON BLOCK1.KEY=BLOCK2.KEY
```

---

PS На предприятии используют некий RunScript, чисто написаное мини-оконное приложение для сотрудников, где можно использовать только `SELECT` и выгружать готовую таблицу в Excel для дальнейших манипуляций с данными.

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста, что такое _местный SQL менеджер (Oracle)_?

Comment: Вынесите условие по TIN в условия связывания, и там же, снаружи, добавьте отбор по заданному значению.

Comment: Тогда вы должны спросить у тех, кто поддерживает некий RunScript на предприятии. Почему вы решили обратится сюда? Почему вы тогда  назвали это _обычным sql-скриптом_, что вы имели ввиду?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если нужна действительно переменная, а не константное значение литерала `123`, то надо добавить переменную подстановки. Как добавить, зависит от языка, на котором реализован RunScript.

Например, так командой `VARIABLE`, доступной во многих инструментах:

```
variable a number
exec a = 123
select block1.cl1, block2.cl2 
from (
    select 123 tin, 'key1' key, 1 cl1, 2 cl2 from dual
    ) block1
left join (
    select 123 tin, 'key1' key, 3 cl1, 4 cl2 from dual
    ) block2 on block1.key=block2.key and block1.tin = 123

       CL1        CL2
---------- ----------
         1          4
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WITH
temp_a AS
    (SELECT 1234 AS a FROM DUAL),
BLOCK1 AS 
    (SELECT a, b, TIN, cl1 FROM table1), 
BLOCK2 AS 
    (SSELECT a, b, TIN, cl2 FROM table2)
SELECT
    BLOCK1.cl1, BLOCK2.cl2 
FROM
BLOCK1
LEFT JOIN BLOCK2
       ON BLOCK1.KEY=BLOCK2.KEY,
 temp_a
WHERE
  BLOCK1.TIN=temp_a.a AND   
  BLOCK2.TIN=temp_a.a
```